# Isolate an array element inside nested array and use it as the JSON field value with it's sibling array elements as a field value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, algorithm, dom

My question is about isolating an array element inside nested array and use it as the JSON field value with it's sibling array elements as a field value properties.

## My Array:

#### "S,No.", "id", "date", "time"

```
eachArray = [
    ["1", "4", "2018/07/05", "22:27:35"],
    ["2", "1", "2018/07/05", "22:28:02"],
    ["3", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:51"],
    ["4", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["5", "2", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["6", "1", "2018/07/25", "22:36:55"],
    ["7", "1", "2018/07/25", "21:25:51"],
]
```

---

#### I want to make a JSON object with the format like:

```
jsonArray = {
    "2018/07/05" : ["4","1"],
    "2018/07/22" : ["3","2"],
    "2018/07/25" : ["1"]
}
```

---

My attempt so far:

```js
eachArray = [
    ["1", "4", "2018/07/05", "22:27:35"],
    ["2", "1", "2018/07/05", "22:28:02"],
    ["3", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:51"],
    ["4", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["5", "2", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["6", "1", "2018/07/25", "22:36:55"],
    ["7", "1", "2018/07/25", "21:25:51"],
]

var outerSet = [];
var jsonArray = {};
eachArray.forEach((val, index) =>{
    var outerLast = outerSet.pop();
    var set = eachArray[index][1];
    var dateHere = eachArray[index][3];
    outerSet.push(set);
    if(index !== 0){
        if(outerLast !== dateHere){
            outerSet = [];
            jsonArray[dateHere] = set;
            return;
        }
    }
    outerSet.push(dateHere);
    jsonArray[dateHere] = outerSet;
});
```

Comment: What determines the resulting array inside the object, like `"2018/07/22" : ["3","2"],` ? Where does `["3","2"],` come from?

Comment: i want to concatenate all the id of the same date in the same array neglecting the repetition too.

Comment: 2018/07/05 has two ids... 4 and 1 ==> "2018/07/22" : ["3","2"]

2018/07/22 has three ids... 3, 3 and 2 but double 3 is neglected ==> "2018/07/22" : ["3","2"]

2018/07/25 has two ids... 1 and 1 but double 1 is neglected ==>     "2018/07/25" : ["1"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use a plain object to store date as key and values as a `Set`. Values should be stored on a set so that it won't have duplicates. Then at the end, convert all the Sets to Arrays using `Array.from` function.

```
eachArray = [
    ["1", "4", "2018/07/05", "22:27:35"],
    ["2", "1", "2018/07/05", "22:28:02"],
    ["3", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:51"],
    ["4", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["5", "2", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["6", "1", "2018/07/25", "22:36:55"],
    ["7", "1", "2018/07/25", "21:25:51"],
];

var obj = {};
eachArray.forEach(arr => {
    if(!obj[arr[2]]){
        obj[arr[2]] = new Set();
    }
    obj[arr[2]].add(arr[1]);
});
Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => obj[key] = Array.from(obj[key]));
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: But, reducing the array makes code more organized, rather than checking for a false condition

Comment: your code is on average 45% more faster than the previous one provided by @CertainPerformance

Comment: Not sure how you look at it. Both our answers have the false condition i.e if (!a[date]) a[date] = new Set(); from selected answer check for the false condition. You could put the forEach code on a method call reduce and return the obj from it. It would be more readable that way.

Answer (score 1):

Try `reduce`-ing into an object indexed by date, whose values are `Set`s (to deduplicate), to which you add the number in each item, and then once you've gone through the `eachArray`, convert the `Set`s back to arrays:

```js
const eachArray = [
    ["1", "4", "2018/07/05", "22:27:35"],
    ["2", "1", "2018/07/05", "22:28:02"],
    ["3", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:51"],
    ["4", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["5", "2", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
    ["6", "1", "2018/07/25", "22:36:55"],
    ["7", "1", "2018/07/25", "21:25:51"],
]

const itemsByDate = eachArray.reduce((a, [, num, date]) => {
  if (!a[date]) a[date] = new Set();
  a[date].add(num);
  return a;
}, {});
Object.entries(itemsByDate).forEach(([key, set]) => {
  itemsByDate[key] = [...set];
});
console.log(itemsByDate);
```

Comment: will it affect performance going for each iteration?
i'm working directly from .txt and .json files and the array list can go up to tens of thousands.

Comment: If you have tons of items in the array, and the speed this code provides isn't enough, you might use a `for` loop instead of `reduce`. But using a `Set` and spreading into an array afterwards is definitely better than the alternative, of trying to deduplicate the array on each iteration

Answer (score 0):

```js
const input = [
  ["1", "4", "2018/07/05", "22:27:35"],
  ["2", "1", "2018/07/05", "22:28:02"],
  ["3", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:51"],
  ["4", "3", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
  ["5", "2", "2018/07/22", "21:25:59"],
  ["6", "1", "2018/07/25", "22:36:55"],
  ["7", "1", "2018/07/25", "21:25:51"],
];

const output = input.reduce((accu, [, num2, date,]) => {
  if(!accu[date]) accu[date] = [];
  if(!accu[date].includes(num2)) accu[date].push(num2);
  return accu;
}, {});

console.log(output);
```